# Im new to coding : doing a post request : no errors : but the data is not being sent to my API

Tags: javascript, html

> My HTML Form: Form from which I'm accessing the data and trying to
>   send as a POST request to my API

```
<div id="contactForm">
<h1>Add New Device Here!</h1>
<small>You need to wait for a minute after adding the Device</small>
    <form id = "iform" action="http://localhost:8081/ping" method="POST" name="myForm">
        <input id = "setrname" name = "fooname" placeholder="Router-Name" type="text" required />
        <!-- <input placeholder="Loop-Back" type="text" required /> -->
        <input id = "setloopback" name = "foo" placeholder="Loop-Back" type="text" minlength="7" maxlength="15" size="15" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$">


        <select id="Type" name="Router-Type">
        <option value="CORE">CORE</option>
        <option value="EDGE">EDGE</option>
        <option value="IGW">IGW</option>
        </select>
        <!-- <textarea placeholder="Comment"></textarea> -->
        <input value="Submit" class="formBtn" type="submit" onclick="submitform()">
        <input class="formBtn" type="reset" />

    </form>
</div>
```

> My JavaScript:  Sending the HTML form data by JavaScript

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8081/ping', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function submitform() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(json.flag + ", " + json.status1);
    }
};  
    var insert = {
        loop_back: document.getElementById('setrname').value,
        status1: 0,
        status2: 0,
        status3: 0,
        status4: 0,
        status5: 0,
        status: 0,
        flag: 0,
        rName: document.getElementById('setloopback').value
    };
           xhr.send(JSON.stringify(insert));
```

> Please help me, suggest me how to correct the above code

Comment: Too many unknowns here. How are you determining the data is not sent? Where are you calling that `XMLHttpRequest`? Are you preventing the default form submit process anywhere? If you aren't preventing the default submit the form will post to the action url with just the named form controls and load whatever that url returns from server

Comment: The data which Im trying to post is not getting updated in my DB, if i try to do POST request using Postman it is working

Comment: Need more debugging detail than that. All you have shown is is some simplified front end code. We have no idea what you receive at server or how your server code is set to process that data. Please take some time to thoroughly read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: can you help me prevent the default form submit process, Yes u r correct when i submit the form im just getting my URL back with all Json objects